# Python-Matplotlib : Display xlabel and ylabel

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

So here I have a little problem to display my labels on the axes with set_xlabel () and set_ylabel () on my confusion matrix with my method.

**Here is my code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd

    def plot_pairs_characters_errors_confusion_matrix(self,
                                                      title="Confusion matrix of reccurent error characters pairs",
                                                      family='serif',
                                                      color='black',
                                                      weight='normal',
                                                      size=10,
                                                      font_scale=1,
                                                      display_html=True):
        # dataset
        df_cm = pd.DataFrame(self.confusion_matrix_pair_char_errors, self.letters_normalize, self.letters_normalize)
    
        fig_matrix, axes = plt.subplots()
    
        FONT = {'family': family,
                'color': color,
                'weight': weight,
                'size': size,
                }
    
        # Add title and axis names
        axes.set_title(f'{title}\n', fontdict=FONT)  # title of graph
        axes.set_xlabel('Predicted sentence', fontdict=FONT)  # label title for x coord
        axes.set_ylabel('Reference sentence', fontdict=FONT)  # label title for y coord
    
        # Generate heatmap
        # for label size
        sn.set(font_scale=font_scale)
        # font size, color of confusion matrix
        sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 8},
                   cmap="nipy_spectral_r")
    
       if display_html:
            return fig_matrix
        else:
            return plt.show()
```

**and the current visual rendering:**

[image]

anyone have any idea why it doesn't display labels (axes.set_xlabel => 'Predicted sentence' / axes.set_ylabel => 'Reference sentence')?

Thank you for your time.

[EDIT 1]

When I comment on the seaborn part, the canevas and labels appear but not data, is there a conflict between seaborn and matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's work because I have a lot of errors:

I initialize figure and not a sub figure with subplot like:

```
fig_matrix = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 6))
```

then I made heatmap in a variable :

```
ax = sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 8},
                   cmap="nipy_spectral_r")
```

Finally, I replace this lines :

```
plt.xlabel('Predicted sentence', fontdict=FONT)  # label title for x coord
plt.ylabel('Reference sentence', fontdict=FONT)  # label title for y coord
```

by this line :

```
ax.set(ylabel="Reference sentence", xlabel="Predicted sentence")
```